# Javascript Compilation for migration of D3 js v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization

I am using D3 js V3 for my application (Javascript charting library). I am using mainly for creating charts and almost used many modules like selections, axis, scale, svg, transition, animations, layouts etc.

Now I want to migrate into new Version 4 of D3 js. I have checked release notes and API reference for V4. Still i found difficult for my application to get migrated to V4 since there are many API changes.

So my question, Is there any way to compile my application with D3 js, So that i can avoid errors getting in Runtime environment.

Comment: `any way to compile my application with D3 js`, this just doesn't make sense, JavaScript doesn't compile.  And how would that help with a migration to `v4`?  And what are these mysterious "errors in Runtime environment"?

Comment: My problem here is to compile my .js files and check those errors while compilation not at running time.

Comment: For eg "d3.svg.line" in V3 is changed to "d3.line" in V4, While compilation it should throw error There is no such method as "d3.svg.line" on compiling

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre compiler with D3js or any error highlighter right now.

So you have the check for the changes and do that manually.
Updated document is here https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md